# Invalid file name inside zip file

Tags: filesystems, zip, unzip

I have a ZIP file, and inside that zip file, there's multiple files with invalid file names (for my Debian OS): for example `fileABC£ [abc123].txt`

When I attempt to extract it `unzip data.zip`:

```
error:  cannot create data/subfolder/fileABC� [abc123].txt
        Invalid argument
```

How do I successfully unzip this file?

Comment: Rename it to something valid while it is still in the zip file and then extract it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by using a python script:

```
#Python 2.x

import zipfile

print "[*] Beginning extraction process..."

zip = zipfile.ZipFile('data.zip')
for i, f in enumerate(zip.filelist):
  f.filename = 'extracted_{0:03}'.format(i)
  zip.extract(f)
  print "--- Extracted '%s'" % (f.filename)

print "[*] Done"
```

Comment: Any attempts using `xarchiver` didn't work, so I resorted to Python.